# Position View below RelativeLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Context of the problem:**

I do have a StackLayout with a lot of entries. When the user taps on an entry I do want to show below the tapped entry an info box. This info box should visually be above the next entry (kind of like a tooltip). The entry can have a dynamic height.

**What is my approach:**

Using a RelativeLayout it should be possible to position views outside the bounds of the RelativeLayout which represents the entry.

Something like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" HeightRequest="150" ></BoxView>

    <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow" x:Name="container">

        <Label Text="This is the entry"></Label>

        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=container, Property=Y, Factor=1, Constant=100}"></BoxView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" HeightRequest="150" ></BoxView>

</StackLayout>
```

In this sample code the green BoxView's are kind of the entries before and after the one I do want to show. This is the result:

[image]

This makes actually sense, as I've linked to the Y-Property of the container and added 100 using "Constant".

And this is what I do want to archive:
[image]

I want to have a StackLayout with multiple entries. Whenever I click on one of this entries (yellow) right below an info should appear (blue).

How do I have to specify the YConstraint on the BoxView (which should illustrate the info window) to archive my goal? Or am I on a wrong path and another solution fits better?

Comment: Is `BoxView` an info box? You click the `Label` called "This is the entry",  the info box(BoxView) will appear. Do you want to specify the YConstraint on the BoxView based  on this `Label` like this screenshot? https://imgur.com/a/Q9JW5x7

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I've updated my question with an additional screenshot on what i exactly want to archive. he BoxView is my "info"-window which should appear below the whole RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a demo about your needs, here is running GIF.

[image]

First of all, I create content view.

```
  <ContentView.Content>      
            <RelativeLayout  x:Name="container" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <Entry Text="This is the entry" x:Name="MyEntry" Focused="MyEntry_Focused"  Unfocused="MyEntry_Unfocused">
            </Entry>
        </RelativeLayout>
 
    </ContentView.Content>
```

Here is background code about content view.

```
   public partial class FloatEntry : ContentView
    {
        BoxView boxView;
        public FloatEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             boxView = new BoxView();
            boxView.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            boxView.WidthRequest = 200;
        }

        private void MyEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            container.Children.Add(boxView,Constraint.RelativeToView(MyEntry, (Parent, sibling) =>
            {
                return sibling.X + 100;
            }), Constraint.RelativeToView(MyEntry, (parent, sibling) =>
            {
                return sibling.Y + 50;
            }));
            container.RaiseChild(boxView);

        }

        private void MyEntry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
          
            container.Children.Remove(boxView);
        }
    }

}
```

But If you used this way to achieve it, you want to BoxView to cover the below Entry. You have to put the content view to a `RelativeLayout` as well.

```
  <RelativeLayout x:Name="myRl">

            <myentry:FloatEntry x:Name="myfloat" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" >
                <myentry:FloatEntry.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>


                </myentry:FloatEntry.GestureRecognizers>
            </myentry:FloatEntry>
            <myentry:FloatEntry HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="50"  
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=myfloat, Property=Y, Factor=1, Constant=50}"
                    >
                
            </myentry:FloatEntry>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // I need to use following method to move the Boxview cover the blew Entry
            myRl.RaiseChild(myfloat);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach would be to write your own control which could be named as InfoBoxPopup (bascially a ContentPage) which you open manually once the Entry gets Focused and Close it on Unfocus.

Just be sure that you have on top of every page a grid panel defined.

In the InfoBox.xaml you define your custom style (panel, label, margins, IsInputTransparent?, etc. to show the custom text or other stuff)

```
public partial class InfoBoxPopup : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(InfoBoxPopup));

    public InfoBoxPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string? Text
    {
        get => (string?)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        var rootGrid = GetCurrentPageGrid();
        var rowsCount = rootGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
        if (rowsCount > 1)
        {
            Grid.SetRowSpan(this, rowsCount);
        }
        rootGrid.Children.Add(this);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        var rootGrid = (Grid)Parent;
        rootGrid.Children.Remove(this);
    }

    private static Grid GetCurrentPageGrid()
    {
        var shellView = (ShellView)Application.Current.MainPage;
        var contentPage = (ContentPage)shellView.CurrentPage;
        if (contentPage.Content is Grid grid)  {  return grid; }

        var actualPanel = contentPage.Content;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var children = actualPanel.LogicalChildren;
            var childGrid = children.OfType<Grid>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (childGrid != null) { return childGrid; }
            actualPanel = children.OfType<View>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("No Grid panel could identified to place the info box!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. It should now better illustrate what I try to archive. I think your approach will not work in this case right?